# White tab with dark text

Tags: android, android-styles, android-tablayout

I am using a `TabLayout` and am trying to set the `tabbackground` to *white with dark text*.

I can't seem to change the colour of the text and it seems to remain white.

**This is the style I used:**

```
<style name="TabWhiteText" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/deepEggplant</item>
</style>

<style name="TabWhite" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/deepEggplant</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="TabWhiteMedium" parent="TabWhite">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TabWhiteText</item>
</style>
```

And applied to this:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        style="@style/TabWhiteMedium"
        selectFromListView:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Programatically add colors to your tab texts using `setTabTextColors()` method.Refer to the Documentation
[TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

For adding color resources use ContextCompat.getColor(context,*your color resource id here*) instead of directly giving resource as paramter

Comment: Tried 
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(R.color.deepEggplant, R.color.deepEggplant); But still no good. :(

Comment: Try adding colors as ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.deepEggPlant)

Comment: Turns out it is using a custom view! Just needed to change the TextColor there. Please excuse me while I go out and shoot myself!

Answer (score 0):

**There is a good tutorial here: http://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout**

Which you can use `textColor` with a dark color or tab's Background to white:

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- Your white color maybe -->
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <!-- Or your TabLayout textcolor to dark maybe -->
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Then just use it as the style for `TabLayout`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Or the other customization.

---

**UPDATE:** Also, no need to add a style, just:

```
app:tabBackground="@android:color/white"
app:tabTextColor="@color/darkcolor"
```

**i.e:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
          app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
          app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
          app:tabBackground="@android:color/white" 
          app:tabTextColor="@color/darkcolor"  
          app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

Comment: Tried it (switching in my colours) but still no good. I will try the details from the link and get back.

Comment: @LinX64 please come to the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103525/room-for-meda-and-linx64)